# Using ng-packagr to build Ionic component library

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, angular-cli, ng-packagr

I have a huge need to build a monorepo for my organization's Ionic assets. We produce a suite of applications, and like to share as much as possible in order to reduce our time-to-market. I found `ng-packagr` a week ago and think it's much better than the previous methods I've been using.

In any case, I'm developing a proof-of-concept, and can't get the `ionic-angular` library compiling. `ngc` breaks, and I'm not sure how to go about fixing it.

First, let me share my `package.json` and see if I'm on the right track here:

```
{
  "name": "ionic-packagr-test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": false,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "packagr": "ng-packagr -p ng-package.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.9.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.9.1",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.9.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.1.3",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.6.8",
    "@angular/cli": "^6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.7",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.10",
    "@types/node": "^10.5.2",
    "ng-packagr": "^3.0.3",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.0",
    "tslint": "^5.10.0",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

I have a pretty vanilla component I'm trying to build, just using a shell Ionic blank template and exporting `app.module.ts` in my `public_api.ts` file.

When I run the packager, I get the following error:

```
BUILD ERROR
node_modules/ionic-angular/components/picker/picker-component.d.ts.PickerCmp.html(13,71): : Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
node_modules/ionic-angular/components/input/input.d.ts.TextInput.html(1,928): : Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
node_modules/ionic-angular/components/input/input.d.ts.TextInput.html(1,961): : Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.

Error: node_modules/ionic-angular/components/picker/picker-component.d.ts.PickerCmp.html(13,71): : Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
node_modules/ionic-angular/components/input/input.d.ts.TextInput.html(1,928): : Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
node_modules/ionic-angular/components/input/input.d.ts.TextInput.html(1,961): : Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
```

Could it be possible that I'm using the wrong version of `ng-packagr`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[Found a tutorial after days of looking](https://www.ionicrun.com/create-prepare-for-distribution-and-publish-an-ionic-2-or-3-component/). Will not copy/paste the article -- don't want to plagiarize or suppress traffic from his site.

Essentially, all `dependencies` should become `devDependencies`. If your package uses any `devDependencies` *copy* them as `peerDependencies`.

Comment: Hi, i'm stuck with this error and the given link doesn't work anymore. Can you explain me how did you solve this problem? Actually i don't get the reason why i should change my dependencies into devDependencies. I'm using Ionic v3.9.5 and Angular v5.2.11. Thanks :)